# IndexedDb - fetching the last-added item from an ObjectStore

Tags: indexeddb

Given an object store, how can I go about fetching the latest item from that store without introducing an additional index?  I'm using a `guid` as a keypath so leveraging auto-incrementing keys is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the IndexedDB API that will provide this directly. You'll need to build it yourself, either by using an index or manually tracking the most recent insertion.

There are several approaches:

- Add an insertion timestamp property to the record, and index on it.
- Change the primary key for the object store to be autoincremented, and use an index on the `guid` instead for lookups.
- Have another store (or just a different part of the key space) record the primary key of the last inserted item.

Comment: Does IndexedDb insert to one end or the other so that I can just to `getAll` and delete the first or last?  Results seem inconsistent from the testing I've done.

Comment: Records are ordered by key per the spec. https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-construct - since you're using string UUIDs as keys they'll be ordered lexicographically.